# Random number repetitive occurs in C++

Tags: c++, random

all

I am afraid that I have to bother you with a frequently asked question. Fortunately, my problem seems a little different from the ones you are familiar with.

Here is my code:

```
vector<double> rand_array;
rand_array.resize(length);

srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        double d = rand() % 100;
        d = d/double(100);
        rand_array[i] =d;
    }
```

The codes above do generate a serie of random number between 0 and 1. However, when I run these codes few times (e.g. 100 times), I found that there are some of serie has totally same elements, especially the adjacent series.

May I know why is this? And how can I generate series of random number that really random?

Many thanks in advance, and appologies again for this simple question.

Regards

Long

Comment: Do manage to run your program to check this twice in a single second? Then the seed will be same and the series will be the same as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for your reply. I think your answer is correct. But my program needs to generate few random arrays in a single second. Do you have any idea to solve this? Many thanks. Long

Comment: Since you're using C++, you should look into the new [pseudo-random classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in C++11. Using those you can create multiple instances of random-number generators, each having its own unique seed and sequence.

Comment: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/03/seeding-srand/

Comment: As long as you don't call `srand` more than once, your existing approach will work (although C++11 does have some new, better, random number generators too)

Comment: Only call `srand` __once__. The usual suggestion is call to `srand` once in `main`. If you are calling it somewhere inside a loop you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you use C++11 features, because it is simpler then.

Answer (score 3):

You should only run `srand(time(NULL));`  once in your program, at the beginning of `main()`.

On most systems, `time(NULL)` returns a time in seconds. This means that if you run `srand(time(NULL))` twice in the same second, you will get the same random seed and as a result the same random sequence. For this reason you should not call it more than once.

Comment: Also, the correct use of rand is described here: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html. rand()%max doesn't produce a good approximation of the uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

All generated numbers depends only on  number you pass to `srand`. You pass time there, so if you run it two times in one second you'll get the same sequence.

If you need to run that in program just don't call `srand` multiple times. If you need to be different on different runs of program you may try to make seed more random. For example on unix-like system you may try reading `/dev/random/` for seed